# Why is my CGPoint returning other characters?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, cgpoint, uicontrol

Hi there I am trying to add a label to the centre of the thumb on a custom UIControl. I need to find the centre on the thumb.

I have a function that I'd like to return the thumb centre as CGPoint.

The function is returning really strange coordinates that look like:

```
thumb center coordinates: (5.534284385e-315, 5.356796015e-315)
```

Why am I getting these values? 
Does UIControl have a way to return thumbRect like UISlider? Thank you!!

```
open func getThumbCenterRect() -> CGPoint {

        return thumbCenter
    }



  fileprivate var thumbCenter: CGPoint {

            var thumbCenter = viewCenter
            let angle = rtlAwareAngleRadians(thumbAngle)
            thumbCenter.x += CGFloat(cos(angle)) * controlRadius
            thumbCenter.y += CGFloat(sin(angle)) * controlRadius

            return thumbCenter
        }

@IBAction func onSlideChange(_ sender: MTCircularSlider) {

        let thumbCenter = knobWithLabelView.getThumbCenterRect()
        print("thumb centre coordinates: \(thumbCenter)")

    }
```

output:

```
thumb coordinates: (5.534284385e-315, 5.356796015e-315)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "thumb"? And where is "viewCenter" defined?

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger. Look at the values at each line. Figure out where you are getting an unexpected value. Since you don't tell us about any of the variables involved, it's hard to help.

Comment: You may also wish to avoid naming a local variable the same as the name of the computed property it is in. It's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It's scientific notation. `5.534284385e-315` means `5.534284385 * 10^-315`, which is a *really* small number (a `0.`, followed by 314 zeroes, followed by 55342...`).

In other words, it's a really small number, that's really close to 0 but not quite. Most probably, you'll want to do some rounding to get values that snap to more reasonable accepted values.